# c# Windows Phone 8.1 Twitter Feeds

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-phone-8.1

I have a c# windows phone 8.1 application and I am able to do the login validation using this code:

```
             user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Twitter);

            if (user.UserId != "")
                message = "You are now signed in -" + user.UserId;
            else
                message = "You must log in. Login Required";

            var dialog = new MessageDialog(message);
            dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

I want to retrieve twitter feeds of this particular user.
I tried using TwitterSharp API but it works only for windows phone 8 apps and not 8.1

Answer (score 1):

Your question is way too broad, but there are some steps you can take to get the desired result.

1. Check out [LINQ to Twitter](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/), one of the best Twitter libraries out there
2. Read the documentation about [fetching Twitter feed with this library](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Querying%20the%20Home%20Timeline)

It comes down to doing something like this:

```
var tweets = await (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
                    where tweet.Type == StatusType.Home
                    select tweet).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Its not way to broad. There are Twitter API out there but majority are for windows phone 8
I want an API for windows phone 8.1

Comment: and twitterCtx isnt there for windows 8.1..i had tried that already..sorry for not mentioning

Comment: Of course it is, as there are many different ways of doing it, and you haven't done your research. LINQ to Twitter is available for Windows Phone 8, Windows Phone 8.1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1. twitterCtx is an instance of TwitterContext.